# PyCharm's not executing `django-manage.py` right

Tags: python, django, pycharm

the console says:

[image: pycharm console]

However if i execute the command in `cmd`, it all right, like

[image: cmd]

I guess the config has some problems, but i don't know where. My file structure is like:

[image: files]

and the configuration is like:

[image: run config]

and this:

[image: django config]

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of the Project directory structure from within PyCharm?  You can find this bar usually to the left of your code.  I'm looking for that file tree because it's possible that the folders may not be imported right.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with PyCharm 2.6.3? Does it help if you [configure project root as `Sources`](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/237/20121210195417.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder what can i say...reproduce it in 2.6.3 and everything becomes right. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a known problem with `PYTHONPATH` generation in older PyCharm versions. PyCharm 2.6.3 and later should work fine.